In SpringCloud Sleuth, how can I override the traceId, to use our firm-supplied trace id?
We are using Sleuth to log trace ID's across our microservices using logback. This is working great across most of our services, and we can show all calls related to a request in splunk simply by searching for a trace id. However our primary service uses a non-standard header (called activityID) for the trace id and we can't change that.
Therefore I would like to modify our Tracer to use the activityID if present, as the trace id, instead of the default.
Is this doable?
